# Is CryptDB compatible with ArchLinux?

Tags: ubuntu, archlinux

Specifically, the oldest (legacy) version which was run by the developers on Ubuntu 12.04. May I know why it is compatible on both systems (same Linux kernel?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about an easy installation the answer is: **No**.

If you can perform the installation by hand, you might be able to hack it together.

The [cryptdb installation script](https://github.com/CryptDB/cryptdb/blob/master/scripts/install.rb) runs this:

```
root?()
get_pkgs()
fn(ARGV[0], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
```

Where `root?()` checks if the entire script runs as root.  Running the entire process as root is plain bad.  But Anyhow.

`get_pkgs()` executes this:

```
sudo apt-get install gawk liblua5.1-0-dev libntl-dev         \
             libmysqlclient-dev libssl-dev libbsd-dev        \
             libevent-dev libglib2.0-dev libgmp-dev          \
             mysql-server libaio-dev automake                \
             gtk-doc-tools flex cmake libncurses5-dev        \
             bison g++ make
```

Which will fail on any system that is not Debian based (e.g. Ubuntu, Mint).  There is a chance it will fail on Debian itself too, since `liblua5.1-0-dev` is not the current version of the lua package for it (you would need to enable backports to get it).

Finally `fn(ARGV[0], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])` runs this:

```
service mysql stop
...
service mysql start
```

Which is outdated `init-v` syntax, which Arch Linux does not bother to support anymore (without [systemd-sysvcompat](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/systemd-sysvcompat/) that is, which you can use to call systemd with sysv syntax).

So yeah, if you are willing to hack those pieces:

- change the `apt-get` call into the `pacman` call
- find the equivalent packages (`glib` and `lua` may be a big problem)
- change the `service` calls into `systemd` calls

You might be able to compile cryptdb on arch.